# Opening a window in XUL

Tags: xul, xulrunner, gecko

An exception is being thrown when trying to open a window using window.open in XUL. The exception details: `Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMJSWindow.open]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location:`

The line of code throwing the exception is:

```
newWind = window.open(settings.url, "Dialog", "chrome = yes, width=" + 
          settings.width + ",height=" + settings.height + 
          ",resizable = yes,scrollbars=yes");
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get round this problem.

Comment: Actually window.open() itself throws an error.

Comment: I see that but what's in `settings`

Comment: Where is the XUL? chrome or http?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else has the same problem here is the answer:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=421261

If you have a line in prefs.js like this:
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeURI", "chrome://myapp/content/myapp.xul");

you have to add another one line like this:
pref("browser.chromeURL", "chrome://myapp/content/myapp.xul");

Comment: I also have to add `pref("app.support.baseURL", "https://support.mozilla.com");` to the project preferences in order to avoid application crashes during opening new windows (XULRunner 41)

Answer (score 0):

I have an XULRunner app. my window open line is as follows:

> var win = window.open("about:blank", window_name, "status=yes,scrollbars=yes,minimizable=yes,top=5000,left=1000,width=1000,height=625,resizable=yes,dialog=no,titlebar=yes");

**Notice how there are no spaces?** Try formatting it exactly like mine is and it SHOULD work.

Another tip:

> Convert that window to chrome, via:
>
> var chromewin = win.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation).QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem).rootTreeItem.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);